# error in installing tizen sdk on windows 8 32 bit

Tags: tizen

error in installing  tizen sdk on windows 8 32 bit.
while running the code on cmd

`java -jar InstallManager.jar`

getting error

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
        der.java:58)
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclips
        e.swt.widgets.Shell
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.createShell(Window.java:487)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:430)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
        at org.tizen.installmanager.ui.InstallManagerWindow.main(InstallManagerW
        indow.java:907)
        ... 5 more`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it Solved . I was using the old version InstallManager.jar file . You have to use the newer one and run through cmd .

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-_s0YKP5Db0)! here is solution of your error. go through this steps by step process.

instead of going through executing installer go through command line.